# Help Recognizing Certain Big-O Runtime Complexities

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

I seem to understand basic Big-O estimates such as O(n) and O(n^2), but I am having trouble comprehending certain trickier Big-O estimates.

How can we recognize each of the following Big-O estimates? If one or more examples could be provided as well, it would be very helpful:

1. O(log(n))
2. O(nlog(n))
3. O(2^n)
4. O(n!)
5. O(sqrt(n))

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples:

1. Searching an element in an AVL tree has the complexity O(log(n)) because every comparison rules out half of the remaining elements. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree#Searching
2. Here is a [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) to some sorting algorithms. Many of them have the complexity O(nlog(n)) or 0(n^2).
3. An example for O(n!) would be an algoritm which creates all possible permutations of a list.

unfortunally I am missing an example for O(sqrt(n)).

Comment: Actually, example is $\Theta(n\cdot n!)$ since checking for being sorted is $\Theta(n)$. THis is known as a pessimum sort.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I assume a valid example would be creating all permutations, right?